# Flow & Apex(@Invocable method) : Identify the primary input variable

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, metadata-api, invocable-method

I would like to know if there is a way using service/object (like using Metadata api service) to identify primary parameter in a flow & apex method(@invocable method).

Among multiple input parameters, which is a starting input parameter or the primary parameter of the flow & apex method?